# elements don't seem to show after putting body picture

Tags: html, css

Here's what I did:

```
.bodyimage { 
  background-image: url('px_by_Gre3g.png');
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

However, if I try to put any element such as p, h1, h2, h3 etc. it doesn't show at all.
here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-responsive.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <head>
    <title>Dave's Website</title>
     </head>
    <body class="bodyimage">
    <p><b>test</b></p>
    </body>
```

It's nothing much, just a simple website. I'm not sure why it won't show at all. Can someone help?

Comment: Are you sure that the background image is not just obscuring the text so it's difficult to read?

Comment: Wait, You're right, But it's grey for some reason, how would I fix this?

Comment: can you post a screenshot ?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/1dign0

Comment: @user2550778 what's gray?  You can just change the color of the text with the `color` rule

Comment: Adding a color like: `color: #fff` does that work?

Comment: Nevermind, Fixed it with <font>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your image transparent or partial transparent which caused the text not visible?
Try to change the font color to white or to black, and work from there.

Refer the following site for more information on images and font.
http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_background_images

Answer (score 1):

Your `link` and `meta` is out of the `head`, which isn't valid. Try like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-responsive.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dave's Website</title>
</head>
<body class="bodyimage">
    <p><b>test</b></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Use [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to check your *markup*.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/uzafoy/2/edit) with a different `background-image`.

Answer (score 0):

To add body background in Twitter Boostrap I add `background: url(../img/bg.png) repeat 0 0;` to

```
body {
  margin:0;
  font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
  line-height:20px;
  color:#333;
  background-color:#fff;
  background: url(../img/bg.png) repeat 0 0;
}
```